# Can I retrieve historical Route53 (DNS) records?

Tags: amazon, route53, amazon-aws

Our DNS records on Amazon's Route 53 were inadvertently changed. Is there a way to see what all the records were yesterday?

Or in general, is there a way to see historical DNS records?

Comment: This might or might not help : http://serverfault.com/questions/325190/can-you-lookup-a-domains-past-nameserver-mx-record-history

Answer (score 1):

Here is a summary of the Answers from ServerFault's [Can you lookup a domains past nameserver & mx record history?](https://serverfault.com/questions/325190/can-you-lookup-a-domains-past-nameserver-mx-record-history):

[Omid Kosari](https://serverfault.com/users/156357/omid-kosari) says: http://whoisrequest.org/history/ This one is really cool . No registration needed .

[Professor Falken](https://serverfault.com/users/89796/professor-falken) says: whoisrequest.org only works for com, net, org, info, biz and us domains. For others try using http://dnshistory.org

[Teddy](https://serverfault.com/users/11492/teddy) says: For **.se** domains, the [DNSCheck](http://dnscheck.iis.se/) tool checks if the previous DNS servers are still authoritative, which means you can see what they were in the "Advanced Results" tab.